# CSS hover on translated element

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Can an animating element detect the actual mouse pointer position and add a hover state this way?
In the below example, there is a simple div moving left and right, if you hover over the div it will become black, however when you leave your mouse pointer in the path of the animating element, without moving it, the hover state won't be applied.

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation: move 1s infinite alternate;
}

div:hover {
  background: black;
}

@keyframes move{
  0%{ transform: translateX(0); }
  100%{ transform: translateX(100px); }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The other way around works the same, when you actually hover the div and don't move your mouse, the div will remain black even if the mouse pointer is not actually hovering this element anymore.

So, is it possible to keep switching normal to hover state based on the static position of the mouse pointer?

Comment: A translated element still technically exists in the document at its original location.

Comment: There are many similar questions to be found on this topic, such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333507/hovering-on-element-glitches-transform-transition#

Comment: @isherwood, while it is similar to the above, and it is very likely to be true that the element still technically exists at its original location, which in this case would be at the position without it being translated, however if you wait for the div to move to the right, add your mouse pointer to the left (on its original position) it still won't activate.

Answer (score 2):

it's not possible to do this with translate, because it has a static position. Like isherwood wrote, the translated element will always exist in its original location.
You could do this with absolute positioning, where u really move the element.

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation: move 1s infinite alternate;
  position: absolute;
}

div:hover {
  background: black;
}

@keyframes move{
  0%{ left: 0; }
  100%{ left: 100px; }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Static position is not the reason why, ```translate``` opposed to ```left```- ```right```, however is. You can add ```absolute``` to the above example and it still won't work. It is a good workaround on the provided simplified example, but ```transform``` handles much more than left, right, top, bottom movements. Thanks, though.